# Could there be another planet between Mercury and the Sun?

Tags: solar-system, planet

Could there be another planet between Mercury and the Sun?
Kepler found a lot of planets orbiting its star even 20 times closer than Mercury.
If there were such planets in our system - would it be possible to discover them?

Answer (score 6):

It is very unlikely. While the hypothetical planet [Vulcan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcan_%28hypothetical_planet%29) between Mercury and the Sun was ruled out many decades ago searches for [Vulcanoid asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulcanoid_asteroid) would very likely have detected anything that might qualify as a intra-Mercurial planet.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. There are quite a few capable [telescopes studying the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_solar_telescopes) since some decades. Already Galileo stared at the Sun until he got blind. Don't you think a planet would've been detected if it passed by in [images like these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Sm8PBr3ysc#t=34)? But [Sun grazing comets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2JCKiSO7AA) are pretty common visitors in the corona.

It is a bit weird that a couple of percent of exoplanetary systems have hot Jupiters. They probably didn't form there, but migrated. And still stay there somehow.

Comment: Galileo reportedly didn't go blind due to his observations of the Sun. His blindness is said to have had another cause.